# Get SUM of values in a column after query is ran

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my SQL statement which pulls back all the fills I've had in a certain time frame.  Is there a way to get the list to come up and also pull the SUM of all of them?

```
SELECT customerName, date, gallons 
FROM addFill
WHERE date >= CONVERT(datetime, '3-3-2015' )
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, date) ASC
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: do you want the sum of the fills per customer or for all customers?

Comment: @Tim Strathman did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would write your query as:

```
SELECT customerName, date, gallons 
FROM addFill
WHERE date >= '2015-03-03'
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

I see no value in ordering by the date and not the date/time component.  Also, you might as well just use a recognizable date format for the comparison.

If you want the sum as well, then that is tricky.  One method uses `rollup`:

```
SELECT customerName, date, SUM(gallons) as gallons
FROM addFill
WHERE date >= '2015-03-03'
GROUP BY customerName, date with rollup
```

Answer (score 0):

sums of fills per customer since '3-3-2015'

```
 SELECT customerName, date, sum(gallons)   
 FROM addFill
 WHERE date >= CONVERT(datetime, '3-3-2015' )
 GROUP BY customerName
```

sum of fills for all customers since '3-3-2015'

```
SELECT sum(gallons)   
FROM addFill
WHERE date >= CONVERT(datetime, '3-3-2015' )
```

Comment: I want it to list all the fills in that time frame... then also list total gallons of those fills underneath.. does that make sense?

Comment: As @Gordon Linoff suggested, would you please provide sample input and output? you cannot list the fills and sum of the fills in one dataset